# How to fetch user profile image from Azure Active Directory from SharePoint Online page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, user-profile, sharepoint-rest-api, azure-ad

I have to display all SharePoint Online user's profile information including profile picture on a page in SharePoint Online.

Here some of user has profile picture set in Office 365, while some users have profile picture added in Azure Active Directory.

I am able to use REST API call but it gives me the profile picture of Office 365 users. But I want to pull profile image for SharePoint Online user from Azure Active Directory.

**How I can achieve this?**

One way is using Graph API by Microsoft, But its usage is confusing me. If any one have used Microsoft Graph API to fetch user's profile image from delve then please share some snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Graph API, you can use the below endpoint to fetch photo from Azure AD:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/photo/$value`

So, for example, you have user's email address as `alans@CIE493742.onmicrosoft.com`, then your url will be:

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/alans@CIE493742.onmicrosoft.com/photo/$value`

To get this, you need to set the app permission as

```
Profile photo of any user in the tenant including the signed-in user - User.ReadBasic.All; User.Read.All; User.ReadWrite.All
```

To test your endpoints, sign in to graph explorer and check

[Graph explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#)

[Azure AD Get photo](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/profilephoto_get)

Comment: Here I will have user email address in javascript array. Also I want to know more about authentication part. Also I don't want to see any login window again.

Comment: Authentication is another beast - you need to implement adal js or angular adal js if using angular code. You also need to register your app in Azure with the permission. Check these links - [Authenticating with adal js](http://nickvandenheuvel.eu/2016/01/06/authenticate-an-office-365-user-with-adal-js/) and [Using sharepoint with Adal](http://julieturner.net/2017/01/extending-sharepoint-with-adal-and-the-microsoft-graph-api-part-1-the-setup/)

Comment: I am using from SharePoint online page. So, Once I already logged in. But it shows unauthorized

Comment: That's expected. Please go through the above links. You need to authenticate to azure AD. Setup the azure app and implement adal js, only after that will you get the data.