# Delve shows profile image but PictureUrl property is Null? Why?

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, sharepoint-rest-api, azure-ad

I have to display all SharePoint Online user's profile information including profile picture on a page in SharePoint Online.

Here profile pictures are added in Azure Active Directory.

As mentioned [here](http://blog.atwork.at/post/2014/06/14/SharePoint-Online-UserProfiles-and-the-story-about-synchronizing-with-Azure-Active-Directory), `PictureUrl` property does not synchronize with Azure Active Directory.

But, When I open up the delv of user, the profile picture shown there, but when I try to fetch the user profile using REST API, `PictureUrl` propery is always null?

**Delve:-**

[image]

**PictureUrl Property:**

[image]

Any reason behind this?

I already posted this [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/215659/30145) but it was all about using Graph API. Now my question is regarding `PictureUrl` property.

Comment: I think that's because the pictures are fetched from elsewhere. [Answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39982565/sharepoint-rest-show-current-user-profile-picture) should work at least with my Delve setup's case.

Comment: I am using that only. But it returns default thumbnail everytime. it seems that it does not generate the thumbnail image. If this is the case then the main question is from where its displaying on Delve? If I check image source then it always shows up the same for every image, whether that image is added in Azure AD or Office 365 user profile.

Comment: My bad, can you check with this url - `https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com&size=HR120x120`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Gautam Sheth's answer works perfeclty.
https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email=joe.shmoe@ms.com&size=HR120x120
This always gets profile photo, even if synch fails between Delve (OWA) and UserInfo Table within SP site. The only thing is, when user does not have a photo in Delve (OWA) it returns an blank picture. We can attach to the load event for the pic then and detect it like so:

On Load event for html generated IMG:

```
onload='OnEmptyPic(this)'

function OnEmptyPic(theImg)
{
    var img = new Image();
    var newSrc = theImg.src;
    img.onload = function(){
        if(this.width == 1)
        {
            newSrc = '.../images/person.gif';
            theImg.src = newSrc;
        }   
    };
    img.src = newSrc;
}
```

If image returned from Delve has a width of 1, we just replace it with some other, generic one.